# SEC7123 CORS on Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, xmlhttprequest, microsoft-edge

I am making POST request to cross-origin API using angular $http.post.
Everything works fine on Chrome or Firefox.
The problem occures on Edge:

SEC7123: [CORS] The origin blocked a preflight request where Request Header 'Content-Type' was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header list for a cross-origin request to .

First it creates OPTIONS Request where in Access-Control-Allow-Headers section I can see Content-Type. Then error occures.
I tried various headers, XHR, Ajax, everytime it is the same.

JS Code:

```
   const config =  {
        cache: false,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
        }
    };

    const params = {
        ip_address: window.ip
    };

    return $http.post(url, params, config);
```

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle or something so that I can try and help you with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was about Edge and IE not able to merge multiple ACAH in a single response. So it was backend issue.

Even that Chrome, Firefox etc. can merge it we should not use multiple line headers in API.
The right syntax(from [mozilla developer site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)) is:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: <header-name>, <header-name>
```

Comment: You may require multiple headers like authorization header mandatory for security.